# android SearchView return REsults from array but not updating new info

Tags: android, debugging, android-recyclerview, searchview

So attempting to filter a RecyclerView using a searchview, which is sort of working however little bug I found is that the result is just filling in the information from the first item in the RecyclerView however when clicked or screen refresh shows the proper information that was searched for, I am guessing this is something to do with androidx as the tutorial I was following was prior to androidx.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        adapter = new adapter(mainDishes.this, recipes);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }

    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Recipes> Filtered = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length()== 0){
                Filtered.addAll(mRecipesFiltered);
            }else{
                String FilterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Recipes item : mRecipesFiltered){
                    if(item.getmrecipeName().toLowerCase().contains(FilterPattern)){
                        Filtered.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = Filtered;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
            mRecipes.clear();
            mRecipes.addAll((List)results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

I have been following the codinginflow.com tutorials for this and it works but just bugged out not sure where to begin on this.

Answer (score 0):

instead of your code use this in your searchView.

```
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    String userInput = newText.toLowerCase();
                    List<Recipes> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Recipes recipesList : item) {
                      if(recipesList.getmrecipeName.toLowerCase().contains(userInput){
                            newList.add(recipesList);
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.upToDate(newList);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

and add this below code to your adapter as an function.

```
    public void upToDate(List<Recipes> newList){
    recipesList = new ArrayList<>(); // recipesList is your arrayList in your adapter that you give it from activity
    recipestList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this into my code, and honestly, I am still not getting anywhere not, in this case, it more I probably doing something I should either already have set up or know what to set up. when I enter the Search view changes the 'item' to error and not sure what it is to link up and the account adapter is giving me some sort of situation if you can link me so additional details that would be amazing

Comment: Yes that was my adapter "account adapter" sorry you should use your adapter name